# Binding to specific element of array doesn't update

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I'm developing a WPF application with C# and .NET Framework 4.7 using the MVVM pattern.

I have this property on my ViewModel class:

```
public List<byte> BestIndividual
{
    get { return _bestIndividual; }
    set
    {
        _bestIndividual = value;

        RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(BestIndividual));
    }
}
```

`RaisePropertyChangedEvent` is:

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And the label with the binding in the View is:

```
<Label x:Name="c00" Content="{Binding BestIndividual[0]}" Margin="0" BorderThickness="2,2,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" />
```

I update the property inside an event handler:

```
private void Algorithm_BestIndividualFound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BestIndividualEventArgs best = (BestIndividualEventArgs)e;

    BestIndividual = best.BestIndividual;
}
```

I only get a value on the `Label` and it never changes.

Why is it not refreshing the content of the label?

**UPDATE:**

I have changed the `List<byte>` with a `byte` and it still doesn't update. The new code is here:

```
private byte _bestIn;

public byte BestIn
{
    get { return _bestIn; }
    set
    {
        _bestIn = value;

        RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(BestIn));
    }
}
```

The event where I update the `BestIn` value:

```
private void Algorithm_BestIndividualFound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BestIndividualEventArgs best = (BestIndividualEventArgs)e;

    BestIn = best.BestIndividual[0];
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Label x:Name="c00" Content="{Binding BestIn}" Margin="0" BorderThickness="2,2,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" />
```

Comment: You mean when you assign a value to `BestIndividual[0]` instead of replacing the whole list? Use an ObservableCollection.

Comment: @Clemens, I replace the whole List. I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: You do of course not need an ObservableCollection if you replace the whole list. However, if `best.BestIndividual` always returns the same collection object, the Binding won't update. Make sure you create a new instance, e.g. `BestIndividual = new List<byte>(best.BestIndividual);`

Comment: Define `BestIndividual` as `public ObservableCollection<byte> BestIndividual`. Another point. instead of setting the `BestIndividual` to new object, clear the collection and add the Range. like `BestIndividual.Clear(); BestIndividual.AddRange(best.BestIndividual);` .Since `ObservableCollection` does not provide `AddRange` so define it as mentioned in this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/af496cfd-aae6-41d1-a5b8-fcc4ff6f983e/observablecollectionaddrange?forum=silverlightnet).

Comment: No, don't do that. Using an ObservableCollection is pointless when the whole collection is replaced.

Comment: @Clemens I've tried `BestIndividual = new List<byte>(best.BestIndividual);` but it still doesn't update.

Comment: Well, it should just work. Are you sure you're operating on the correct view model instance, or perhaps on some other one, that you aren't binding to?

Comment: @Clemens Yes, everything works fine except this one. I'm going to try to show all the List instead one element to see what happens.

Comment: I'm going to try with a DataGrid instead.

Comment: @Clemens I have updated the question with another test that I've done.